# How to read line by line a particular length of a file and write it to a list using python programme

Tags: python, file, list

> This is my python programme

```
IPS=[]                                      # creating a list of IP addresses
w=sum(1 for line in open('my_dict.json'))   # w=total no. of lines in my_dict.json file 
ins=open("my_dict.json","r")
for lin in ins:          # from each line of my_dict.json,storing IP addresses in IPS   
    IPS.append(lin[2:10])
print IPS
```

> Inside my_dict.json file IP addresses are stored as ["10.0.0.1/8"] ["10.0.0.2/8"]....["10.0.0.10/8"] ["10.0.0.11/8"]....etc..Now the problem is, for the IP values from 10.0.0.1 to 10.0.0.9 we can store that exactly in IPS as 10.0.0.1 to 10.0.0.9.But after that while 10.0.0.10,10.0.0.11 etc. comes then only 10.0.0.1 writes to IPS removing the last digit.Because we are writing lin[2:10] only.If we use it as lin[2:11] then the '/' value that immediately follows after ip address within the range 10.0.0.1 to 10.0.0.9 will get written to IPS.So how should I modify programme to receive letters from 2 to 10 i.e lin[2:10] for ip addresses in the range 10.0.0.1 to 10.0.0.9 and after that letters from 2 to 11 i.e lin[2:11] for ip addresses 10.0.0.10,10.0.0.11,10.0.0.12 etc..

Comment: Please show us the sample data from `my_dict.json` and please format the question.

Comment: your IP always start with 10.0.0

Comment: ack, stop.  Use the `json` module to parse your presumably JSON encoded file.

Comment: Once you're parsing the `json` correctly, you can use `split` to divide the Python strings on the `/` character, since I believe the JSON encoded strings will be "10.0.0.1/8" etc even after decoding. "10.0.0.10/8".split('/')[0] will give you just the "10.0.0.10" part without being dependent on the length.

Comment: @thefourtheye my_dict.json contents are IP addresses in the format["10.0.0.1/8"] to ["10.0.0.20/8"] in each line of my_dict file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use regular expression to extract the IP part, code like this

```
import re
p = re.compile('\d+?\.\d+?\.\d+?\.\d+?')
IPS=[]                                      # creating a list of IP addresses
w=sum(1 for line in open('my_dict.json'))   # w=total no. of lines in my_dict.json file 
ins=open("my_dict.json","r")
for lin in ins:          # from each line of my_dict.json,storing IP addresses in IPS  
    result = p.search(a)
    if result is not None
        IPS.append(result.group(0))
print IPS
```